# How do I get a spark dataframe to print it's explain plan to a string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a system in which component A passes sql to component B, B then runs the sql via apache spark, and returns a result.

For debugging purposes, I'm putting in a second communication channel where A can pass sql to B and request and explaination of the plan.

The code in B looks something like this:

```
def handleExplain(sql: String, extended: Boolean): String = {
    val dataFrame = sparkContext.sql(sql)
    dataFrame.explain(extended)
}
```

The problem is that 'explain' doesn't return a string, it just prints the explain plan to the console.  How do I get the string contents of what's printed to the console?  Is there another function, or do I have to lift it from the console?

Answer (score 11):

All query plans, including string representation, can be accessed through corresponding `QueryExecution` object. For example to get full execution plan:

```
val ds: Dataset[_] = ???

ds.queryExecution.toString
```

only logical plan:

```
ds.queryExecution.logical.toString
```

optimized logical plan:

```
ds.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.toString
```

or executed / physical plan:

```
ds.queryExecution.executedPlan
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `spark: SparkSession`, something like

```
def handleExplain(sql: String, extended: Boolean): String = {
  val dataFrame = spark.sql(sql)
  import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExplainCommand
  spark
    .sessionState
    .executePlan(ExplainCommand(dataFrame.queryExecution.logical, extended))
    .executedPlan
    .executeCollect()
    .map(_.getString(0))
    .mkString("\n")
}
```

Based on https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L499

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already issuing SQL statements to spark, you can simply prepend `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` to your sql statement

```
def handleExplain(sql: String, extended: Boolean): String = {
    val explain = if (extended) "EXPLAIN EXTENDED" else "EXPLAIN"
    sparkContext.sql(s"$explain $sql").as[String].collect.mkString
}
```