# How to view the logical and physical plan of a Spark Streaming application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am looking for a method to print the execution plan of a Streaming application in Spark. I know that it is possible to [print the plan of a SQL Spark application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614122/how-do-i-get-a-spark-dataframe-to-print-its-explain-plan-to-a-string). However, I want to show the logical and physical plan of a stream application. Here is my app:

```
package org.sense.spark.app

import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{HashPartitioner, SparkConf}

object TestStreamCombineByKey {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second.
    // The master requires 2 cores to prevent from a starvation scenario.
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))

    // Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

    // Split each line into words
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))

    // Count each word in each batch
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    // val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
    val wordCounts = pairs.combineByKey(
      (v) => (v, 1), //createCombiner
      (acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1), //mergeValue
      (acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2), // mergeCombiners
      new HashPartitioner(3)
    )

    // Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
    wordCounts.print()

    ssc.start() // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination() // Wait for the computation to terminate
  }
}
```

Comment: UI should be good enough, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the UI (from History Server) to get a slightly different perspective.

What you request here is not possible. Why? You are using dStream with "RDDs". Logical and Physical plans only apply to Dataframes and Datasets.

You would need to use debugToString and use the spark-shell and insert that into the right code location. That said, dStreams need compilation and cannot just run in the spark-shell as far as I remember, so I would paste the relevant non-dStream code from this into the spark-shell only.

Also, this is all deprecated, my advice is to invest in Spark Structured Streaming.